# How do you stored orders that have not met it's requirements while other orders are been made

Tags: python, list, bots, binance-api-client

IMAGINE .....

So if I have 10 unripe apples in a box which will represent to orders.

And the requirement is the apples must be ripe

And 6 of those apple's are ripen which already met the requirements.

I will have 4 left in the box, but while those apple's are waiting to meet the requirements another set of 10 apple are been added to the box and waiting to meet the same requirements.

I need a code to represent this issue

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). “Show/tell me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue. We expect you to make an honest attempt, and then ask a specific question about your algorithm or technique.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please follow the reading suggestions from the above comment. Based on your description, I would advise you to research about the [queue](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/queue-data-structure/) data structure.

Comment: Also, what the heck with those tags? `bots`? `binance-api-client`??

Answer (score -1):

I think this question is a little confusing!!

Based on your example, 4 apples left in box, 10 more added so now 14 in box or does the box have a max capacity of 10??

Are the '10' new apples added to the box every time we check for ripe apples or do they happen at different times? Can we check for ripe apples more then once before new apples are added???

What happens to the ripe apples? Do they need to be moved to a new box or are they just removed and 'eaten'!! (Deleted)

But I had a go anyway, code is below...

Please take note of the comments under your original post....

This isnt what Stack overflow is about, I'm learning to code so fancied putting something together for you but I am not sure if it is what you are looking for...

```
import random

AppleBox = []
RipeApples = []

def AddTenApples(lst):
    
    for _ in range(10):
        Apple = {'apple':'unripe'}
        lst.append(Apple)
    return lst
        


def MakeSomeApplesRipe(lst):
    n = len(lst)
    N = random.randint(0,n)
    for x in range(N):
        lst[x]['apple'] = 'ripe'
    return lst


 
def RemoveRipeApple(lst,location):
    location = [x for x in lst if x['apple']=='ripe']
    lst = [x for x in lst if x['apple']=='unripe']
    return lst, location



AppleBox = AddTenApples(AppleBox)
AppleBox = MakeSomeApplesRipe(AppleBox)
AppleBox, RipeApples = RemoveRipeApple(AppleBox, RipeApples)


print('Apple Box :', AppleBox)

print('Ripe Apples :', RipeApples)
```